# Push Notification on the open web

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, push-notification, opera, samsung-browser

I'd like to know the current status (2020) of implementation of the web standards (Web Push Protocol + VAPID) across major browsers.
Safari is using Apple Push Notification Service and I know that Firefox and recently Chrome implemented it in the full standard way:

- no need to have a `gcm_sender_id` in the manifest.json
- only need the VAPID public key in the subscription options
- no developer registration to any service

Did Samsung Internet, who used FCM/GCM, passed to the standard way like chrome?
What is the status on Opera and Edge?